# Bouncing balls on Custom view - Android

Tags: android, performance, canvas, android-canvas, ondraw

I have this code what works just fine: On this custom View, 3 Ball object is bouncing continuously:

```
public class AnimatedView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private Context mContext;
    private boolean running = true;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 10;
    ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();



    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        h = new Handler();
        balls.add(new Ball(mContext, AnimatedView.this.getWidth(), AnimatedView.this.getHeight(), false));
        balls.add(new Ball(mContext, AnimatedView.this.getWidth(), AnimatedView.this.getHeight(), false));
        balls.add(new Ball(mContext, AnimatedView.this.getWidth(), AnimatedView.this.getHeight(), false));
    }


    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (running) {
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    };

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {

        if (running) {
            for (Ball ball : balls) {
                if (ball.getX() < 0 && ball.getY() < 0) {
                    ball.setX(this.getWidth() / 2);
                    ball.setY(this.getHeight() / 2);
                } else {
                    ball.setX(ball.getX() + ball.getxVelocity());
                    ball.setY(ball.getY() + ball.getyVelocity());
                    if ((ball.getX() > this.getWidth() - ball.getBall().getWidth()) || (ball.getX() < 0)) {
                        ball.setxVelocity(ball.getxVelocity() * -1);
                    }
                    if ((ball.getY() > this.getHeight() - ball.getBall().getHeight()) || (ball.getY() < 0)) {
                        ball.setyVelocity(ball.getyVelocity() * -1);
                    }
                }
                c.drawBitmap(ball.getBall(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
            }
            h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
        }
    } 
}
```

My only problem is, that it needs a lot of memory and hardware resources.
On my brand new phone, it's running perfectly smoothly (using 130-140MB memory with 3 bouncing balls), but it's terrible on my older phones, where the app can only use 20-30MB.

What, and how should I refactor my code in order to be more efficient (I'm pretty sure, that this is the problem).

It seems to me, that these calculations are necessary for every ball in every new frame.
Even if I set FRAME_RATE to 33 (which means cca. 30FPS), there is no noticable difference in my older phones.

Thanks!  :)